# Pre execute code before any AndroidTestCase is executed

Tags: android, unit-testing, testcase

There is any way to run some code before any AndroidTestCase is executed?

An idea would be to use extend AndroidTestCase but I would like to have something like the an Application.onCreate to run some code for all the test cases.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, is this exactly same what the setUp() method does?
and you may use tearDown() to execute code that you may need to happen at the completion of text case.

Comment: It could work, but I want something that it will be executed at the very beginning and it will be for all the testcases without specifying it in the setUp() method